# How to create a database out of many log files and doing some SQL like queries?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

Consider you have many log files that you need to process all of them and to create a database out of it which will be able to be queried with SQL queries.
Which technology should I use for it?
Is `LINQ to SQL` appropriate?

Comment: better use NLog and save them in database

Comment: What is NLog? do you have an example?

Comment: I'm not searching for a logging management, I already have log files to process

Comment: No LINQ for SQL is not for this. ]

Comment: You can parse the content and put it in RDBMS. If you were using linux this can simply done by `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is used with structured data, if your log files are simply raw text files, then you are out of luck. What I would suggest is to parse the log files, create local data structures that encapsulate the important data from the file

You can have something like

```
class LogFileRow
{
  DateTime timestamp{get; set;}
  int ActivityId{get; set;}
  string Message{get; set;}
....
}
```

Then fire LINQ queries on collections of `LogFileRow`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use something like the Filehelpers library http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/ to get the logfiles in your database.

A simple foreach based on the DirectoryInfo class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) where your logfiles are will do.

Wether you use Linq-2-sql or another technology for the insertion depends on the number of records. Linq-2-sql is not very suitbable for large batch insertions because it generates a single insert statement per record. I would combine **SqlBulkCopy** with **FileHelpers**. It will be easy and high performane.

Afterwards, Linq-2-sql would be fine to query against the table(s) in the database.